# When to stop MCMC within collapsed Gibbs?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, numerical-integration

I am setting up a Hierarchical model whose target distribution is $p(\theta,w|y)$, $\theta$ being a reduced set of high-level parameters, $w$ being a data augmentation of very high dimension, and $y$ being the data.

The big problem is that there is a coupling between $w$ and $\theta$  making vanilla Gibbs sampler unusable.
My strength is that I can sample from $w$ quite efficiently. However, I cannot evaluate $p(w|\theta, z)$.

Decorrelation methods like [Yu and Meng's](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jcgs.2011.203main) gave disappointing results. I also have bad results with blocked methods from [Rue and Held](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289221213_On_block_updating_in_Markov_random_field_models_for_disease_mapping) because I update $w$ in several steps and therefore I cannot get the Holy Grail of $p(w, \theta|z)/p(w|\theta, z) = p(\theta|z)$.

Since smart methods did not work, I am going for low-brow strategy. Since I have an efficient integrator on $w$, I want to use the efficient sampler for $w$ in order to compute Metropolis ratios of the shape:
$$p(\theta'|y)/p(\theta|y) = \int p(y|w)p(w|\theta')dp(w|\theta', y) ~~/ ~~ \int p(y|w)p(w|\theta)dp(w|\theta, y).$$

I have two interrogations. The first is when I should stop the integration needed to update $\theta$. Isn't there a way to cut corners in the evaluation of $\int p(y|w)p(w|\theta)dp(w|\theta, y)$ ? Any reference would be appreciated. I also wonder if anyone thinks that I have missed out something obvious.